# using jquery to detect number ranges

Tags: jquery, range

Im trying to use jquery to detect a number above or below:

```
    $(".input-text").val()) > 499) {}
    $(".input-text").val()) < 1000) {}
```

Is there a way to set a range such as 500-1000 and the having jquery execute a function based on the range?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is $(".input-text") an unique element?

Comment: `var value = $(".input-text").val();  if(value > x && value < y){}`?

Comment: Do you want to execute the mentioned function whenever the value of the textbox changes?

Comment: You need to parse the value for numerical comparison:- `parseFloat($(".input-text").val(),10) > 499`

Comment: @roasted yes its a unique element, i can always trail it down to the exact element in case

Comment: Vanilla javascript will do it, as with tymeJV and Memolition's answer - is there some other functionality you need?

Comment: Are your values dynamically changing all the time? or is it a one time load onto the DOM?

Comment: @techfoobar yes what im trying to do is hav jquery detect a number between that range then execute a function based on the range it's detected the number

Comment: @BrianDHall i would use it but im mainly using jquery for most of my dynamic elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do

```
$(".input-text").change(function() {
    if (this.value > 499 && this.value < 1000) {
        console.log("working");
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/XZ4dq/

Comment: This worked for what i needed best, thanks a lot. I was able to set multiple to work for different ranges, thanks agin

Answer (score 5):

You need to parse the input because it is just a string not a number

If your input is just Int:

```
if(parseInt($(".input-text").val(),10) > 499) {}
if(parseInt($(".input-text").val(),10) < 1000) {}
```

If your input is Float:

```
if(parseFloat($(".input-text").val(),10) > 499) {}
if(parseFloat($(".input-text").val(),10) < 1000) {}
```